# How do you name a docker container?

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, docker

On Ubuntu 12.04.4 I installed Docker 1.1.2.  I have tried various attempts at setting the image id using:

```
sudo docker run -i -t --name=container1 ubuntu date
```

However, my attempts seem to fail.  Every time I do a `docker ps -a` the image id has been randomized.  I can set the hostname if I add `-h container1` but I want to set the image id.  What am I missing here?  Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Sorry for the late response, I'm on version 1.1.2 myself now and the correct way of naming your container is as follows:

```
sudo docker run --name="testname" image command
```

testname is the name you want to give the container.

Have fun dockering!

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't `-name container1` work? I guess it *should* equal to `--name=container1` (I don't have a Docker instance near me to try out), but you never know.

Comment: No neither work.

Answer (score 0):

Try:
    sudo docker run -i -t --name container1 ubuntu date

As used in this example: https://docs.docker.com/examples/postgresql_service/

Comment: No this does not work.  I am wondering if it is something to do with the version of docker that I am using.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible this is just a misconception between the container name and container ID? The container ID will always be a random hash. There is a separate column for the container name:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                             COMMAND                CREATED             STATUS                     PORTS               NAMES
3109b5cbbee2        firehoseprivate_firehose:latest   /bin/sh -c 'bundle e   17 hours ago        Exited (-1) 17 hours ago          firehoseprivate_firehose_1
```

In this example, I have started the container using:

```
docker run --name firehoseprivate_firehose_1 firehoseprivate_firehose
```

The name column gets set to the name I specified. But it still gets a unique ID for reference. You can reference the container either by name or ID. For example:

```
docker inspect firehoseprivate_firehose_1
```

And...

```
docker inspect 3109b5cbbee2
```

Are both valid.