# How do I change docker host name after the image creation?

Tags: docker

I'm learning docker 1.8. I wanted to change the hostname of the container *after* I create them. I tried to edit `/etc/host` inside the container and got overwritten every time I `attach` then `start` the image. I tried to edit the following file, and the hostname gets overwritten.

```
[root@localhost ~]# docker inspect high_blackwell | grep hostname
"HostnamePath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/15b84f7012383b1af2d4c8c6443506cdff3b19cb1d87d3dfdcb10df126c4eec3/hostname",
```

[root@localhost ~]#

None of these answers worked for me

[How do you name a docker container?](https://serverfault.com/questions/616767/how-do-you-name-a-docker-container)

***Note: This question was asked due to a lack of understanding of how docker works. I assumed Docker acted like a VM when I asked this question.***

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I am not sure if you mean you want to set the hostname of a new container or of a running container. You say you want to do it after creating the container, but then you also say you're "starting the image". If you haven't `start`ed the image you haven't yet created the container -- a container is what you get when you start an image.

#### You're creating a new container

You can set the hostname on the command line:

```
docker run --rm -h "example.com" -t -i ubuntu bash
# ...
root@example:/# hostname
example.com
```

#### Your container is already running

This is more difficult. You'll want to keep an eye on [this Docker issue](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/8902) but until it's resolved you can't do much more than to edit `/etc/hosts` I think. The `hostname` command won't work.

Comment: Yeah, using commend run is creating a new container. I thought my data are saved every time I exit the container and run it again.

Comment: In `docker-compose.yml` there is the [`hostname` option](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#domainname-hostname-ipc-mac_address-privileged-read_only-shm_size-stdin_open-tty-user-working_dir) as well.

Answer (score 11):

To change the hostname of a running container, you can use the "nsenter" command. You will have to be root on the host, though.

We can list the namespaces on the host with the "lsns" command:

```
# lsns
        NS TYPE  NPROCS   PID USER COMMAND
4026531836 pid       73     1 root init      
4026531837 user     101     1 root init      
4026531838 uts       73     1 root init      
4026531839 ipc       73     1 root init      
4026531840 mnt       72     1 root init      
4026531857 mnt        1    14 root kdevtmpfs
4026531957 net       73     1 root init      
4026532300 mnt       28  1785 root /usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/supervisord -c
4026532301 uts       28  1785 root /usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/supervisord -c
4026532302 ipc       28  1785 root /usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/supervisord -c
4026532303 pid       28  1785 root /usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/supervisord -c
4026532305 net       28  1785 root /usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/supervisord -c
```

The ones with pid 1785 are my docker container. The namespace type that handles hostnames is "uts", so let's run hostname in that namespace:

```
# nsenter --target 1785 --uts hostname foo
```

Now "hostname" in your container should yield "foo"!

Comment: excelent, i believe that this command can do so many other things like kernel parameters...

Comment: Works inside a container as well. I have a linux container with that runs the init process to support multiple services. Running the command "sudo nsenter --target 1 --uts hostname <my new hostname>" from inside the container did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

1.Stop container and service

```
sudo docker stop CONTAINER_NAME
sudo service docker stop
```

2.Edit config file (JSON) [You should always make backup first]

```
    /var/lib/docker/containers/CONTAINER_ID/config.json

Replace

    "Hostname":"WHATEVER"

with

    "Hostname":"NEW_HOSTNAME"
```

3.Start container and service

```
sudo service docker start
sudo docker start CONTAINER_NAME
```